# ドメイン取得したのですがポート番号を含めたものをそのドメインにすることは可能なのでしょうか？

Tags: dns, さくらインターネット

さくらのVPSをつかって"133.〇〇〇.〇〇.〇〇〇:ポート番号"を取得したドメインにしたいのですがどうすればいいのでしょうか？
サクラサーバーも不親切でIPアドレスまでしかドメインにすることができません

Comment: 短い回答としては恐らく「不可能」です。 参考: [ポート番号毎にドメインを割り当てる - teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/226064)

Comment: 解決したい課題はなんでしょうか? 「ポート番号を含めたアドレスにドメインを割り当てる」ではない解決方法があるかもしれません。

Comment: サクラサーバー内に立てたASP.NETのサーバーを80だったり344とかにできればいいようなのですが80も344もできませんでした